# Recover output value of Azure ARm template with terraform output

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using terraform and Azure ARM template, in order to configre event grid with a particular azure function, I am trying to recover some values in a terraform output.

Indeed, I have this ARm template deployment to have the systems keys of a particular function:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "functionApp": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "functionAppId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionApp'))]"
    },
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "systemKeys": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[listkeys(concat(variables('functionAppId'), '/host/default'), '2018-11-01').systemKeys]"
        }
    }
}
```

My deployment working well, because I can see in Azure Portal that there are in output a json objecy like this:

```
{
    "durabletask_extension": "ASensituveValueIDoNotShareForDurableTaskExtension==",
    "eventgrid_extension": "ASensituveValueIDoNotShareForEventGridExtension=="
}
```

Now the purpose is to get one of this value in a terraform output.
I tried these but I have got some errors:

```
output "syst_key" {
    value = "${azurerm_template_deployment.function_keys.outputs["systemKeys"]}"
}

Error: on outputs.tf line 69, in output "syst_key":   
69:     value = "${azurerm_template_deployment.function_keys.outputs["systemKeys"]}"
    |----------------
    | azurerm_template_deployment.function_keys.outputs is empty map of string

output "syst_keys" {
  value = "${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.function_keys.outputs, "systemKeys")}"
}

Error:  on outputs.tf line 77, in output "syst_key":   
77:     value = "${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.function_keys.outputs, "systemKeys")}"
    |---------------- 
    | azurerm_template_deployment.function_keys.outputs is empty map of string

Call to function "lookup" failed: lookup failed to find 'systemKeys'.
```

In order to trigger eventgrid on this function I have to recover the values in terraform output of systemKeys from my ARM deployment template. I know that the deployment is working well, I just don't know how to recover theses values with terraform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, you need to take care that only the type **String**, **Int** and **Bool** are supported in Terraform. So you need to change the output type in the template, then you can output them in Terraform. For more details, see [outputs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html#attributes-reference). And the right output in Terraform is below:

```
output "syst_key" {
    value = "${azurerm_template_deployment.function_keys.outputs["systemKeys"]}"
}
```

Comment: You save my life, and indeed it was a rookie mistake. Using this ARM template and terraform I need to set the value type as a string. Now I recover correcty my value. Thank you, you save my day