# ARM deployment failed for event grid subscription on endpoint webhook url

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, terraform, azure-eventgrid

Using terraform and Azure ARm template , I am trying to create an azure event grid subscription on a function.

This the ARM using for the event grid subscription:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "eventGridTopicName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Event Grid custom topic."
            }
        },
        "eventGridSubscriptionName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The name of the Event Grid custom topic's subscription."
            }
        },
        "eventGridSubscriptionUrl": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The webhook URL to send the subscription events to. This URL must be valid and must be prepared to accept the Event Grid webhook URL challenge request. (RequestBin URLs are exempt from this requirement.)"
            }
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The location in which the Event Grid resources should be deployed."
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": [{
            "name": "[parameters('eventGridTopicName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-01-01"
        },
        {
            "name": "[concat(parameters('eventGridTopicName'), '/Microsoft.EventGrid/', parameters('eventGridSubscriptionName'))]",
            "type": "Microsoft.EventGrid/topics/providers/eventSubscriptions",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-01-01",
            "properties": {
                "destination": {
                    "endpointType": "WebHook",
                    "properties": {
                        "endpointUrl": "[parameters('eventGridSubscriptionUrl')]"
                    }
                },
                "filter": {
                    "includedEventTypes": [
                        "All"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[parameters('eventGridTopicName')]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#version-2x-runtime) in order to create the subscription, we have to recover a system key in order to create the complete webhook endpoint. So following this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57355443/recover-output-value-of-azure-arm-template-with-terraform-output), I have used an ARM template to recover the system key called `evengrid_extension`.

So everything goes well except during the arm deployment of the eventgrid subscription. I have this error:

> Error waiting for deployment: Code="DeploymentFailed"
>   Message="At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please
>   list deployment operations for details. Please see
>   https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details." 
>   Details=[{"code":"Conflict","message":"{\r\n
>       \"status\": \"Failed\",\r\n
>       \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"ResourceDeploymentFailure\",\r\n
>       \"message\": \"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",\r\n
>       \"details\": [\r\n      {\r\n
>           \"code\": \"Url validation\",\r\n
>           \"message\": \"The attempt to validate the provided endpoint https://myFunctionName.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid
>   failed. 
>                        \For more details, visit https:
>   //aka.ms/esvalidation.\"\r\n      }\r\n    ]\r\n  }\r\n}"}]

I check my code n terraform in order to be sure that I am using the right value for all parameters in this arm template and everything is ok. I have the right topic name, the right endpoint with all value filled in. So I don't understand what I am missing here. I was wondering too if I am using the right system key. I know that there are a system key named **durabletask_extension**, and another one named **eventgrid_extension**. But in fact I have tried with both and the same error occured.

---

**Update**

Just notice that the keys i-e **durabletask_extension** and **eventgrid_extension** are both system keys. So in my arm template to recover these works well and I recover the right system key by using only **eventgrid_extension**.

---

Here my code for terraform:

```
resource "azurerm_eventgrid_topic" "eventgrid_topic" {
  name                = "topicName"
  location            = var.main_location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.name
}

resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "eventgrid_subscription" {
  name                = "EventGridSbscription"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.environment.name

  template_body = file("./arm/event-grid-subscription.json")

  parameters = {
    eventGridTopicName = "${azurerm_eventgrid_topic.eventgrid_topic.name}"
    eventGridSubscriptionName = "eventgrid-myFunctionName"
    eventGridSubscriptionUrl = "https://${azurerm_function_app.function.name}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid?functionName=${azurerm_function_app.function.name}&code=${lookup(azurerm_template_deployment.function_key.outputs, "systemKey")}"
    location = var.main_location
  }

  deployment_mode = "Incremental"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_template_deployment.function_key
  ]
}
```

So I do not understand why my susbription deployment failed, or what I am missing in order to automate this settings with terraform.

Following the doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication#checklist) I understand too that:

> If you don't have access to the application code (for example, if
>   you're using a third-party service that supports webhooks), you can
>   use the manual handshake mechanism. Make sure you're using the
>   2018-05-01-preview API version or later (install Event Grid Azure CLI
>   extension) to receive the validationUrl in the validation event. To
>   complete the manual validation handshake, get the value of the
>   validationUrl property and visit that URL in your web browser. If
>   validation is successful, you should see a message in your web browser
>   that validation is successful. You'll see that event subscription's
>   provisioningState is "Succeeded".

So, there is a way to make a validation using terraform or another way to automate this validation ?

Comment: for test purpose: Go to the portal and from your *EventGridTrigger function* take its Subscription Url (located on the Integrate page) and use it in the terraform code.

Comment: also, you can test your EventGridTrigger function for validation response using a postman request POST *subscriptionUrl*, header *aeg-event-type=SubscriptionValidation* and payload from the SubscriptionValidationEvent example described in the  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication

Comment: I have a similar problem setting up a subscription URL to a function app in an ARM template. I believe the issue is the query string parameter in the URL; if you look at the validation failure it does not show the ?functionName={whatever} in the URL. If I set up the subscription manually through Azure portal it works properly.

Answer (score 2):

The template is right, you just misunderstand something in the `eventGridSubscriptionUrl`. Take a look at the [URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid#azure-cli). The URL shows like this:

**Version 2.x runtime**

```
https://{functionappname}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid?functionName={functionname}&code={systemkey}
```

**Version 1.x runtime**

```
https://{functionappname}.azurewebsites.net/admin/extensions/EventGridExtensionConfig?functionName={functionname}&code={systemkey}
```

The `functionappname` is what you set as the value `azurerm_function_app.function.name`, but `functionname` is not.

You get the existing function name through the Azure REST API [Web Apps - Get Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/getfunction).

And in Terraform, it seems there is no function resource in the function app for you to create. But you can also use the template to create the function and output the function name. Then you can set it in the URL. You can get more details about function in the Azure Template [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2018-11-01/sites/functions#template-format) and the function name shows in the property.

Comment: your answer is really interesting, and I have tried making an event grid subscription using ARM template for function. In that way I have well a functionAppName, and a functionName. But I am still getting the same issue. I think, it's about the validationUrl. See my edit in my initial post.

Comment: @french_dev As I see in the document, you need to get the system key from the function master key, but you use the default key.

Comment: see my update in my initial post. In fact I recover the right system key with an arm template. SO the problem not comes from this point. But thank you for suggesting me t check again this part.

Comment: @french_dev What trigger do you create? I test Http trigger and azure event trigger, only the azure event trigger can successfully.